# How to set global variables in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, global-variables

I developing a app and I want to get some data with CURL, I'm using Guzzle to get this informations. In every request I need to put the param `api_token`. I don't have problems with requests but I need to create a globals variables or config this values. My ask is: how I can define this values and after use them in every request that I made?

```
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.iugu.com/v1/payment_token?api_token=API_TOKEN', [
      'json' => [
          'account_id' => $account_id,
          'method' => $method,
          'test' => true,
          'data' => [[
            'number' => $number,
            'verification_value' => $verification_value,
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'last_name' => $last_name,
            'month' => $month,
            'year' => $year
          ]]
      ]
    ]);
```

When I create a project in pure PHP. I use this:

```
require 'environment.php';

$config = array();

if(ENVIRONMENT == 'development') {
    define("BASE_URL", "http://localhost/plans/");
    define("ACCOUNT_ID", "SECRET");
    define("ACCESS_TOKEN", "SECRET");
    $config['db_name'] = 'SECRET';
    $config['host'] = 'localhost';
    $config['db_user'] = 'root';
    $config['db_password'] = 'XXXXXX';
} else {
    define("BASE_URL", "http://www.blablabla/test");
    define("ACCOUNT_ID", "SECRET");
    define("ACCESS_TOKEN", "MY_TOKEN");
    $config['db_name'] = 'INSERIR DATABASE';
    $config['host'] = 'INSERIR HOST';
    $config['db_user'] = 'INSERIR USUARIO';
    $config['db_password'] = 'INSERIR SENHA';
}

global $database;

try {
    $database = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$config['db_name'].";host=".$config['host'], $config['db_user'],$config['db_password']);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "Erro: ".$ex->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

And in the `environment.php`:

```
<?php

define("ENVIRONMENT", "development");
//define("ENVIRONMENT", "production");
```

Comment: put them in your `.env` file ?

Comment: I would refactor this into a dedicated service and have an interface for it, and then bind the service to the contract in a service provider. Then in that service provider, fetch the API key from the `.env` file using the `config()` helper. If you're making similar requests in multiple places then that's harder to maintain than a single service class.

Comment: I have given 2 solutions to create global variables in Laravel. Please check once and let me know if works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All these values should be in your `.env` file. Then you need to read these values in a config file by using `env()` helper:

```
'variable' => env('SOME_DATA'),
```

And then you'll be able to use these values globally with:

```
config('config_file.variable')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alexey! Works like charm!

Answer (score 3):

For Global Variables, you can create a file like `constants.php` within `config` folder.

Inside `constants.php` file, you can define your global variable `api_token` like below:

```
<?php
return [
    'api_token' => env('API_TOKEN','https://api.iugu.com/v1/payment_token?api_token=API_TOKEN'),
];
?>
```

You can access this variable now using either of these two functions:

```
Config::get('constants.api_token')
config('constants.api_token')
```

For Blade file, do like below:

```
{{ config('constants.api_token') }}
```

Other alternative is to set Global Variable in `__construct` function in `Controller.php` file located at Controllers folder like below:

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public $api_token;

    public function __construct(){
    $this->api_token = "https://api.iugu.com/v1/payment_token?api_token=API_TOKEN";
}
```

I don't know exactly from your question that you want to make `api_token` or `ENVIRONMENT` as Global Variable but both solutions can resolve your issue.

Comment: Not a great idea as then you can't easily change it per environment, In any case It would work better as a class constant and not property.

Comment: @dhinchliff Please check again, try offline any time! Both solution will work. I am already using :)